How to send custom emojis with a telegram bot
This is the code am using to send a custom emoji in JS using grammy.js but it doesn't really work.
const message = " dsfs";
teleBot.api.sendMessage(CHANNEL_ID || "", message, {
  entities: [
    {
      type: "custom_emoji",
      length: message.length,
      offset: 0,
      custom_emoji_id: "5100686784019301387",
    },
  ],
});

I have gone through a few discussions around the same topic -
How to send custom emoji from Bot in Telegram
https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/discussions/3375
Both of these mention buying a username on Fragment for 5000 TON ($44k) and then applying it to the bot. Is this the only method or is there something much simpler as telegram premium only costs like $33/year.
Can a userbot be used to send custom emojis?

please don't use unrelated tags

Unfortunately not! There's no other method to send custom emojis than purchasing your bot a username from Fragment.
Pretty harsh decision from Telegram for sure.

Can't I just create a new username and use that? And if I buy a username from Fragment, what next?

You must purchase a username from Fragment to allow your bot to use custom emojis. Once you purchase username from Fragment, you can assign it to your bot from the Fragment platform itself (My Assets section). It costs another 1k TON as far as I know. Once assignment is completed your bot will be able to use custom emojis.
